# Paypal IPN Transaction ID's

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

This is probably fatigue setting in, but I am a little confused about the use of Transaction ID's in IPN transactions.

I understand that PayPal assigns a transaction ID and POSTs that back with all the other gumf. However, it also states that a single transaction may generate more than one IPN message (i.e. as the payment status moves from PENDING to CONFIRMED). In which case more then one message witht he same transaction ID may be received.

My confusion is around all the samples provided (by PayPal themselves as well as PayPalTech). Every script I have seen only processes the first message received via IPN - if the transaction ID already exists (especially when writing IPN transactions to a database), then it is effectively ignored.

If this is the case, are they not potentially missing out on those transactions which start PENDING and then become CONFIRMED?

Am I missing something or just making this more complicated than it needs to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional transaction ids are generated when for example you're funding the purchase using a credit card. So then there's one TransId for charging the CC, another TransId for sending the money to the receiver. But the receiver only sees "his" TransId, not the CC-related. So there will always be one TransId returned. The Transaction Id is not changed when the status of a transaction is changed (pending/confirmed, etc).

Comment: Thats my point. If this is the case, won't the sample scripts ignore any new messages as they have the same transaction id? The scripts all check to see if the transaction id already exists in the database. If it does, they do nothing. Wouldnt it be better to check if the transaction ID and transaction status are the same?

Comment: If the TransId already exists then there's no point storing it again. However it would probably make sense to re-query the status, if it's not confirmed. But most samples don't handle error situations very well.

Comment: OK, thats what I thought. Just sanity-checking really. Cheers @Haukman